# Does Ruby or Rails have an equivalent of pandas.read_sql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg, python-db-api

So in Python, I am used to using something like

```
pd.read_sql(sql_query, connection_object)
```

in order to grab data from a remote database. But when forming a similar connection object in Ruby:

```
require 'pg'

@connect_obj = PG.connect(:host => host, :dbname => db , :user => user , :password => pwd , :port => port )
```

what can Ruby do in order to run something like `pd.read_sql(sql_query, connection_object)`?

Comment: do you mean just Ruby or Ruby on Rails?

Comment: see https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel or you can use activerecord as well

Comment: @emaillenin either

Comment: @maxpleaner how would I use activerecord?

Comment: @Flair you know, I think sequel would be easier.

Comment: @maxpleaner that is true, but I like to know all of my options.

Answer (score 2):

With Rails, the usual way is to create a model class for your table and then use `ActiveRecord` methods.

But if you want to run some general queries without using any model classes, you can try it this way:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT * FROM users').each { |row| puts row }
```